# Flutter: Passing Multiple Data through Navigator.Push and then Pop the data back

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I pass multiple variables to a new screen, and then pass that data back?
I can successfully pass the Username back but now I need at least 6 variables.

So far, this is what I have come up with. I can't seem to figure it out.

```
 Future<void> createUserInFirestore(FirebaseUser currentUser) async {
// 1) check if user exists in user collection in database (according to ID)
DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.document(currentUser.uid).get();    
if (!doc.exists) {
  // 2) if user does not exist, take them to user create account.     
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => new CreateAccount(username: username),
    ),
  );
  // 3) get username from create account, use it to make new user documents in users collection.
  usersRef.document(currentUser.uid).setData({
    "uid": currentUser.uid,
    "username": username,
    "user_profile_photo": currentUser.photoUrl == null? {} : currentUser.photoUrl,
    "email": currentUser.email,
    "account_created": timestamp,
  });

}
```

And this is my callback for my submit method;

```
 _submit() {
final form = _formKey.currentState;
if (form.validate()) {
  form.save();
  SnackBar snackbar = SnackBar(
    content: Text("Welcome $widget.username!"),
  );
  _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
  Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
    Navigator.pop(context, username);
  });
}
```

I have been stuck for 4 days now trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** OK, you say i did for one variable, and ask for at least 6 variables.

```
Map<String, dynamic> yourMap = {
    "uid": currentUser.uid,
    "username": username,
    "user_profile_photo": currentUser.photoUrl == null? {} : currentUser.photoUrl,
    "email": currentUser.email,
    "account_created": timestamp,
};
```

1- Update `Navigator.pop` like that 
`Navigator.pop(context, yourMap}`

2- Update `Navigator.push` like that 
`Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => WhichPageYouWantPage(yourMap)));`

---

Your `CreateAccount` codes is fine, just update `Navigator.push` like that (U can bring back everything) `String username = await Navigator.push(...);`

Comment: Sorry, where do I put the map?

Comment: Here, use `Map` instead of `username` in this code `Navigator.pop(context, username);`

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {
  // your data in form of map
};
```

Pass data to your page using:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => YourPage(data)));
```

And retrieve data in your page like

```
class YourPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;

  YourPage(this.data);

  // other code
}
```